# Jackson polymorphism issue without enableDefaultTyping

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm facing a weird issue during deserializing of a JSON file that has polymorphic types.

My json file looks like this

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "version": 1,
  "fileNames": [
    "xyz.abc",
    "xyz/abc"
  ]
  "vehicles": [
  "java.util.ArrayList",
    [
      {
        "name": "Car"
      },
      {
        "name": "Train"
      },
    ]
  ]
}
```

My code looks like:

```
private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER;

    static {
        OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
        OBJECT_MAPPER.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        OBJECT_MAPPER.configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL, true);
        OBJECT_MAPPER.addMixIn(Vehicle.class, VehicleMixIn.class);
    }


  @JsonCreator
    public Config(
            @JsonProperty(value = "name", required = true) final String name,
            @JsonProperty(value = "version") final Integer version,
            @JsonProperty(value = "Vehicles") List<Vehicle> listofVehicles,
            @JsonProperty(value = "paths") final List<String> paths, {
      
        fileName = name;
        versionNumber = version;
        vehicles = listofVehicles;
        mPaths = paths;
    }
/**
     * A JSONMixin helper class to deserialize Vehicles.
     */
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "name")
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "Car", value = Car.class),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "Train", value = Train.class),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "Bus", value = Bus.class)
    })
    private abstract class VehicleMixIn {
        public VehicleMixIn() {
        }
    }
```

The way I read the json file

```
try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(configFile.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            config = Config.fromJson(reader);
}
```

I'm unable to read the polymorphic vehicle type.
I get the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (VALUE_STRING), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property 'name' that is to contain type id  (for class abc.def.Vehicle)
```

This works if I do OBJECT_MAPPER.enableDefaultTyping(), however then I'm unable to read the 'paths' field. How do I make this mixIn work?

I've tried all types of defaultTyping

Comment: Is that really your complete JSON file? It's missing the opening curly brace.

Comment: @dnault fixed it :)

Comment: `"java.util.ArrayList",` in your json, is it right json file

Comment: @PratapiHemantPatel yes it is. And unfortunately I can't change it :(